# Reason for "SDS_ENABLE is not set" error when migrating a server from Informix RSS to SDS?

Tags: informix

I'm going to migrate my Informix system from RSS to SDS. After doing the configuration, when I try to start the server, it shows the following error.

```
SDS_ENABLE is not set
```

Please tell me any other reason for that error beyond the SDS_ENABLE is 1.

Comment: The Informix 12.10 online documentation is in the [IBM Informix Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.welcome.doc/welcome.htm).  There's a table of contents on the left which can be missed if you don't know it's there; you may need to click on an arrow to expose it.  There's also a search box, and typing `SDS_ENABLE` finds a number of links, including [`SDS_ENABLE` configuration parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0149.htm).  I'm not clear whether you've set that in your server's $ONCONFIG.

Comment: yes online documentation is really good. RSS is used to improve security. SDS is used to improve performance. Prior to setup SDS you need to share your database volume between all the SDS nodes; for example with nfs or iscsi. Regarding IDS first you have to setup the sqlhosts files on all the node, then start (oninit) and activate the primary SDS node with onmode -d set SDS ... Next you modify SDS_ENABLE in the each onconfig's node and start these nodes with oninit.